# Global database connection inside functions

Tags: php, mysql, global-variables, require

Trying to global database connection in all functions in a .php file.

**sql.php:**

```
<?php
$servername = "XXXXX";
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";
$dbname = "XXXXX";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

**save.php**

```
$conn = require_once('../path/to/sql.php');

function save()
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `content` (title, text, cat)
VALUES ('".$_POST["title"]."', '".$_POST["text"]."', '".$_POST["category"]."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        show();
    }
    $conn->close();
}
```

well i want to get sql.php with require_once and then make it global then put this in save() function.

error is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in
>   /homepages/3/xxxxxxxx/htdocs/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/content.php on line 37

actually i don't know this way to make it global is correct or not, so please help me to choose best way to make a global database connection inside the functions.

Comment: variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: i read this doc but still can't figured out. i mean still got error

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
define('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DATABASE_DBNAME', 'db');
$conn = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_DBNAME);
```

Named constants are great for static global data.

Also you just need to do

```
require_once 'path/to/sql.php';
```

And not

```
$conn = require_once 'path/to/sql.php';
```

$conn is already being set in your require_once.

Comment: @ITSolution i answered this 12 minutes ago if you bother to read the comments

Comment: @ITSolution we must be missing code then somewhere.  $conn is obviously being reset to something else at somepoint.  Did you remove the `$conn = require_once 'path/to/sql.php'` and replace it with just `require_once 'path/to/sql.php'`?

Comment: @Squeegy yes, still same error. yes you right about $conn. it's just was my mistake to define var.

Comment: @ITSolution so were you able to get it working then?